# Windows 7 Family pack upgrade with Windows XP Home OEM

Tags: windows-7

I currently am running Windows 7 RC (Build 7100) <strike>2</strike> and want to make the jump to Windows 7.  I was looking at the Windows 7 Home Premium Family pack and from what I understand it is identical to the Windows 7 Home Premium DVD, just with three licenses, correct?

Anyway, my computer came with Windows XP Home SP2, which I would assume is OEM, I have a Dell OS reinstallation disk, which, as far as I can tell is just the Windows XP CD with a different  label, and that it doesn't ask for a CD-key.

Would I be able to perform a clean install with the Windows 7 Home Premium Family Pack media? Would it simply ask for (and accept) my OEM disk, or would I have to reinstall XP first before I perform the clean install (I read somewhere that the upgrade editions look for previous versions of Windows on your hard drive), or would it view my existing RC<strike>2</strike> install as a previous version?

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 won't ask for your old media to do a clean install with upgrade media.  You need to either install Windows XP and then upgrade (which will force you to choose a clean install) or you need to follow the [directions](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/clean_install_upgrade_media.asp) on Paul Thurrott's site on how to clean install using upgrade media.

Answer (score 0):

XP asked for the previous version CD (and so did many earlier versions of Windows).  But Vista and Windows 7 must have the upgrade started from within a working version of Windows.  That should include the RC (there was no RC2) of Windows 7.  (Installing from the RC of Win7 should not upgrade - it should do a clean install.  In order to do an upgrade, you'd have to hack Windows or the CD (I don't remember - and frankly, I don't recommend it).

Comment: Hmm I thought this was RC2 (build 7100).. Anyway, thanks, I did not want to do an "in-place" upgrade, I wanted to do a clean install, but the way I've always done it was to boot off the optical media and reformat. So just to clarify, the upgrade (not in-place, i mean Win7RC -> Win7 RTM license) will not start by booting of the optical media, only by running the autorun or whatever in a previous version of Windows?